# How could I add permissions for a button in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like to do as I do for my orders using the `` has_role``` for my button but it does not work and I find no alternative, do you have any?

```py
@buttons.click
@buttons.has_role("Admin")
async def btn_close_yes(ctx):
    channel_close = ctx.channel
    await ctx.reply(":wastebasket: Supression du channel dans `3 secondes` :wastebasket:")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await channel_close.delete()
```

Comment: Which library are you using for buttons?

Comment: I use ```from discord_buttons_plugin import *```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include a check based on users roles. `ctx.member` is a User and not a Member so it needs a bit of a workaround.

```py
member = ctx.guild.get_member(ctx.member.id)
# This filters role by name. You can also filter by id
role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'My role', ctx.guild.roles)
if role not in member.roles:
    return
```

If you need it in multiple places, you can refactor it into a separate function or your custom decorator.